# Remove spaces from $contactname php

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

I am trying to remove the spaces from $contactname. Right now if I view the code below I get:

First Last

If I replace $_SESSION['name'] with 'first last' I get:

firstlast

Any ideas on why this is only working when it is a static field?

```
$contactname=$_SESSION['name'];
$contactname = preg_replace('/( *)/', '', $contactname);
echo $contactname."\n";
```

Updated Code with same problem:

```
$contactname=$_SESSION['name'];
$contactname = str_replace(' ', '', $contactname);
echo $contactname."\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should use the character class for whitespace, `\s`:

```
$contactname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $contactname);
```

In order to replace anything like a space that might be in $_SESSION, or use `str_replace` if it is guaranteed to only be spaces (because it doesn't need the regex engine and goes faster):

```
$contactname = str_replace(' ', '', $contactname);
```

Comment: So I edited my code to look like:

    $contactname=$_SESSION['name'];
    $contactname = str_replace(' ', '', $contactname);
    echo $contactname."\n";

for some reason it is still not stripping the space. It will strip it however if I put static content in place of the $_SESSION name.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_SESSION['name'])`? If you look at the source, does the $_SESSION['name'] variable contain `&nbsp;` the char code for a non-breaking space, which you are just seeing as a space in the browser?

Comment: Shelhamer you are 100% correct this is what I get: khurram&nbsp;ahmed. How do we remove the &nbsp; will the str_replace do that?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to fix it. I changed the str_replace to look like: ('&nbsp;', '', $contactname);

Thanks you very much

Comment: Good that you figured it out.  You might want to look into `strip_tags()` and `html_entities_decode()` for filtering your input, as a helpful tip.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use preg_replace to remove spaces.  Use:

```
str_replace(' ', '', $contactname);
```

It's faster.